# Using SimpleMembershiProvider with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I am trying to use SimpleMebership Provider with Windows authentication mode enabled in IIS. I use membership apportunities such as CreateAccount, GetRoles and e .t.c to store information for domain users. I am create **domain\user** login with my provider and when user **domain\user** try to enter my site I authorize him with my locale user with same name in membership db. Everything works fine except sometimes my site is redirecting to Account/Login. Sometimes, when a user clicks on the links, the site redirects him to `Account / Login`. I found solution on stackoverlow that I could use below configuration to solve this issue

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
```

But in my case I could not disable SimplemembershiProvider in windows authentication mode, because I use it. Could you suggest any solution in my case to solve redirection to login page?

Comment: Can you clarify what's happening? What exactly is the problem?  Is it redirecting you to a login page when it's not supposed to?

Comment: Sometimes, when a user clicks on the links, the site redirects him to `Account / Login`.

Comment: does it do that even though they're still logged in/authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simply removed SimpleMembershipProvider and create my own provider based on MembershiProvider class. After this everything works fine.